# Why is DEBUG still writing to Output?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have set-up my debugging like this:

```
TextWriterTraceListener[] listeners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] 
{
      new TextWriterTraceListener("C:\\debugROAR.txt")
      //new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out)
};

Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);

Debug.WriteLine("Some Value", "Some Category");
Debug.WriteLine("Some Other Value");
Debug.AutoFlush = true;
```

However, Console.Out has now been commented out - BUT it still write to console? How do I stop that? I only want to write to file.

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Debug.Listeners.Remove(Debug.Listeners["Default"]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default trace listener is still attached. Remove it using `.Clear()` or similar:

```
TextWriterTraceListener[] listeners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] 
{
      new TextWriterTraceListener("C:\\debugROAR.txt")
      //new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out)
};
Debug.Listeners.Clear(); // Remove the default listener
Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);

Debug.WriteLine("Some Value", "Some Category");
Debug.WriteLine("Some Other Value");
Debug.AutoFlush = true;
```